# Why do ajax returns a TypeError undefined error if it calls a function on success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Im trying to get the contents of a json file from my localhost and display it on my page, i made a custom function `displayProfile` that is called inside the `success` whenever the file exist on the directory. the problem is i get an error saying:

> TypeError: data is undefined

**JQUERY code version 1**

```
$.ajax({
    url:'api/profile.json',
    dataType:'json',
    data: {format: "json"},
    success:function(data){
        displayProfile();
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //alert(textStatus+' '+errorThrown);
        $("#myfirstname").text('Firstname');
        $("#mymiddlename").text('M.I.');
        $("#mylastname").text("Lastname");
        $("#mybiography").text("Biography")
        $("#myprofpic").attr("src","default.jpg");
        $("#mycoverphoto").css("background-image","url(defaultcover.jpg");
        }
});

var displayProfile = function(data){
    // initialize values
    var firstname = data.profile.firstname;
    var middlename = data.profile.middlename;
    var lastname = data.profile.lastname;
    var biography = data.profile.biography;
    var prof_pic = data.profile.profpic;
    var cover_photo = data.profile.coverphoto;

    // set values
    $("#myfirstname").text(firstname);
    $("#mymiddlename").text(middlename.substr(0,1)+".");
    $("#mylastname").text(lastname);
    $("#mybiography").text(biography)
    $("#myprofpic").attr('src',prof_pic);
    $("#mycoverphoto").css("background-image","url("+cover_photo+")");
};
```

But it works when i just copy the content of the function and paste it inside the success like this:

**JQUERY code version 2**

```
$.ajax({
    url:'api/profile.json',
    dataType:'json',
    data: {format: "json"},
    success:function(data){
        // initialize values
        var firstname = data.profile.firstname;
        var middlename = data.profile.middlename;
        var lastname = data.profile.lastname;
        var biography = data.profile.biography;
        var prof_pic = data.profile.profpic;
        var cover_photo = data.profile.coverphoto;

        // set values
        $("#myfirstname").text(firstname);
        $("#mymiddlename").text(middlename.substr(0,1)+".");
        $("#mylastname").text(lastname);
        $("#mybiography").text(biography)
        $("#myprofpic").attr('src',prof_pic);
        $("#mycoverphoto").css("background-image","url("+cover_photo+")");
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //alert(textStatus+' '+errorThrown);
        $("#myfirstname").text('Firstname');
        $("#mymiddlename").text('M.I.');
        $("#mylastname").text("Lastname");
        $("#mybiography").text("Biography")
        $("#myprofpic").attr("src","default.jpg");
        $("#mycoverphoto").css("defaultcover.jpg)");
        }
});
```

Can you guys explain why version 2 works? i am a beginner with this languages. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use the data in displayProfile() you have to send them as parameter

Comment: `displayProfile();` => `displayProfile(data);` Voting to close as typo.

Comment: And an additional advice. Don´t use `success` use `.done()` instead.

Comment: @elsololobo: There's nothing wrong with using `success`. But if you want to use the promise API, use `then` rather than `done`, it's the modern promise way.

Comment: Or you could pass the function as a reference `success: displayProfile,`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `done` guarantees that it does not proceed until the request is finished, whereas success can just run through. jquery doc´s say to use `.done` over `.success`. For this case it doesn´t matter, but it is the better and saver implementation! Also .success is depreciated.

Comment: @elsololobo: *"`done` guarantees that it does not proceed until the request is finished, whereas `success` can just run through"* No, it can't. `success` is only called when the request is complete and successful, never before. The `.success` **method** is deprecated. The `success` option (used above) is **not**.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, with the deprecated part you are probably right. But try to write an async ajax with a callback-function using success. You will find out that the callback is called without any data in it (in some cases). That was the result I got, therefore I decided to use `done`

Comment: @elsololobo: *"But try to write an async ajax with a callback-function using success. You will find out that the callback is called without any data in it (in some cases)."* No, that is simply completely incorrect. That happens with using `XMLHttpRequest`'s built-in `onreadystatechange`, it does **not** happen with jQuery's `ajax`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the `data` returned in the success handler:

```
success:function(data){
    displayProfile(data);
},
```

> Why version 2 Works?

That is because you are referring to the data directly in the success handler and data is defined in the function's params.

While in your first case you didn't passed the `data` returned from the ajax. So, results in *`undefined`* and ***Does not work***.

---

And as above in the comments ***Rory*** mentioned to use the function as a reference instead, then it will be able to resolve the `data` as it is defined in the function's param:

```
success: displayProfile,
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the data in your function:

```
success:function(data){
    // Provide the data to the function as parameter
    displayProfile(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url:'api/profile.json',
    dataType:'json',
    data: {format: "json"},
    success:function(data){
        displayProfile(data);//Must have the corresponding parameters
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //alert(textStatus+' '+errorThrown);
        $("#myfirstname").text('Firstname');
        $("#mymiddlename").text('M.I.');
        $("#mylastname").text("Lastname");
        $("#mybiography").text("Biography")
        $("#myprofpic").attr("src","default.jpg");
        $("#mycoverphoto").css("background-image","url(defaultcover.jpg");
        }
});

var displayProfile = function(data){
    // initialize values
    var firstname = data.profile.firstname;
    var middlename = data.profile.middlename;
    var lastname = data.profile.lastname;
    var biography = data.profile.biography;
    var prof_pic = data.profile.profpic;
    var cover_photo = data.profile.coverphoto;

    // set values
    $("#myfirstname").text(firstname);
    $("#mymiddlename").text(middlename.substr(0,1)+".");
    $("#mylastname").text(lastname);
    $("#mybiography").text(biography)
    $("#myprofpic").attr('src',prof_pic);
    $("#mycoverphoto").css("background-image","url("+cover_photo+")");
};
```

Comment: Thanks guys,  i learn a lot, just a follow up question, what's the difference between .done and success? and their advantages and disadvantages? also which is a better practice between them?